# Run a python script from bamboo

Tags: python, python-2.7, bamboo

I'm trying to run a python script from bamboo. I created a script task and wrote inline "`python myFile.py`". Should I be listing the full path for python?

I changed the working directory to the location of `myFile.py` so that is not a problem. Is there anything else I need to do within the configuration plan to properly run this script? It isn't running but I know it should be running because the script works fine from terminal on my local machine. Thanks

Comment: do you get any errors in the log? And do you have Python installed on Bamboo server?

Comment: I get the error that it can't import a module that I downloaded to the server using pip. Python is installed, that is not the problem. I think it might be a bathing error now but when I check on the server there seems to be no problem.

Comment: Have you tried checking that python is on the system path and not the user path, this can cause issues especially when bamboo is configured to login as one user and you are logining in as another.

Answer (score 0):

I run a lot of python tasks from bamboo, so it is possible. Using the Script task is generally painless...

You should be able to use your script task to run the commands directly and have stdout written to the logs. Since this is true, you can run:

'which python' -- Output the path of which python that is being ran.

'pip list' -- Output a list of which modules are installed with pip.

You should verify that the output from the above commands matches the output when ran from the server. I'm guessing they won't match up and once that is addressed, everything will work fine.

If not, comment back and we can look at a few other things.

For the future, there are a handful of different ways you can package things with python which could assist with this problem (e.g. automatically installing missing modules, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Script Task directly with an inline Python script to run your myFile.py:

```
/usr/bin/python <<EOF
print "Hello, World!"
EOF
```

Check this page for a more complex example:
https://www.langhornweb.com/display/BAT/Run+Python+script+as+a+Bamboo+task?desktop=true&macroName=seo-metadata